# iFrame Css Pseudo-classes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to visually identify my iframe for users navigating with the keyboard e.g. tabbing

From what i can tell, only :hover has an impact

```
iframe { border: 1px solid #fff; }    
iframe:hover { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

When trying to use :focus or :active they have no effect:

```
iframe:focus, iframe:active{ border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

How do we let visitors know they have tabbed to an iframe element?  I'm not trying to style the contents of the iframe, just the iframe itself.  Why does it support :hover but not the others?

**Update**

tabindex is not an option

a) it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/qk034swn/
b) the page becomes invalid if using XHMTL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a `:focus` or `:active` in CSS won't be enough, since the iframe is not **"focusable"**.

**Edit** - 
Now, for the solution

- <strike>`tabindex` attribute can be used.</strike>. After exploring a bit I discovered that this can't be done.

Here is a simple way to do that

**HTML** - `<a href="#"><iframe src="http://foo.com"></iframe></a>`

**CSS** - `a:focus iframe{border:3px solid red;}`

In short, we will be using `<a>` tag to make `iframe` focusable. **Demo** - https://jsfiddle.net/ctqfacgw/1/

Comment: Re update, this isn't a solution either, you are focusing on the anchor, rather than the iframe.  If you press the return when you activate the red border, you are taken to the anchor href - not on the iframe contents.  So you end up at http//mywebsite/# which makes the situation worse!

Comment: Did you want tabbing to take the user to content inside the iframe? Because if that is the case then your question description is bit misleading, which says "How do we let visitors know they have tabbed to an iframe element?".

Answer (score -1):

Is the  actually tabable? I think you need make the tab key actually focus on the  instead of something in the contents of the . You would need to have an href set on the  element or use the global HTML attribute `tab-index="0"` (0 so it doesn't interrupt the normal flow of tabbing).

Comment: Yes it's tabable, see this demo, tab through the page, tabindex has no effect:  https://jsfiddle.net/qk034swn/